# TaxonomyInternalService.GetSuggestions Microsoft.Sharepoint.Client equivalent

Tags: client-object-model, csom

With the TaxonomyInternalService.json/GetSuggestions endpoint, I can retrieve all terms with synonyms that start with some specified text. I am attempting to do this with Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy, but it seems like my only options are to get terms by label match information or to get all the terms in the group. Is there a way to get all terms based on whether it starts with some specified characters? ie termset.GetSuggestions("abc") returns terms that have synonyms/labels that start with "abc", or at least contain "abc"

Answer (score 0):

Guess I didn't understand LabelMatchInformation correctly. I can just query it like this:

```
LabelMatchInformation lmi = new LabelMatchInformation(clientContext);

lmi.TermLabel = "start";

lmi.DefaultLabelOnly = false;

lmi.TrimUnavailable = true;

lmi.StringMatchOption = StringMatchOption.StartsWith

var terms = termset.GetTerms(lmi);
```